# NSTabViewController - How to create a custom transition?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard, nstabviewcontroller

I have an `NSTabViewController` which have attached 6 tabs (`NSViewController`s). From IB I have the possibility to chose from a few predefined transitions, but I don't like any of them. So my question is : How can I make my own transition?

PS: I'm use StoryBoards on my project.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following method with limited success (still looking for a better solution, or to eliminate some visual hiccups that occur).

Create a subclass of `NSTabViewController`, being sure to set the custom class of the tab view controller in your storyboard to your newly created subclass.

By default, `NSTabViewController` makes the following three calls when switching from one tab view item to another:

1. `tabView:willSelectTabViewItem:`
2. `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:options:completionHandler:`
3. `tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:`

In your custom subclass, you can override `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:options:completionHandler:` to implement your own switching method.

I've used something like the following:

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController
     toViewController:(NSViewController *)toViewController
     options:(NSViewControllerTransitionOptions)options
      completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion {

      NSWindow *window = self.view.window;
       NSView *superview = fromViewController.view.superview;

      [superview replaceSubview:fromViewController.view with:blankView()];
      [window resizeToSize:toViewController.view.frame.size]; // category defined elsewhere
      [superview replaceSubview:blankView() with:toViewController.view];
      window.title = toViewController.title;
}
```